# Mediaplayer gap before playing another

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a few media players setup to play one after another on a button click however there is a noticeable gap between the media players playing ie. once mediaplayer one has finished there is a half a second before mediaplayer two plays, for the purpose I'm using the mediaplayers for the gap in audio is very noticeable, so what I'm asking is, is there a way to remove this gap. Now I don't know if I'm going wrong using different mediaplayers each time however this is what I've come up with so far.
Basically I've got `onCompleteionListeners` for each mediaplayer and within those I have the next mediaplayer play until the last. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpButtonThree = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audioReplay);
            if (mpButtonThree==null){
                //display a Toast message here

                return;
         }
            mpButtonThree.start();
            mpButtonThree.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpButtonThree) {
                    mpButtonThree.release();
            mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, audioReplayPrimary);

            if (mpButtonOne==null){
                //display a Toast message here

                return;
         }
            mpButtonOne.start();
            mpButtonOne.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpButtonOne) {
                    mpButtonOne.release();
                    mpButtonTwo = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, audioReplaySecondary);
                 if (mpButtonTwo==null){
                        //display a Toast message here

                        return;
                 }
                 mpButtonTwo.start();
                 mpButtonTwo.setOnCompletionListener(new soundListener1()
                {
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If You play files in series you can use single media player object.
create function that plays next media file and put it into OnCompletion.
This should remove gap between playing, because You don't have to release and create media player every time

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I kind of follow but I'm not sure how I would implement this (still quite new), if possible could you show me the basics of what you mean please?